# Make a quiz game (real time multiplayer) in android

Tags: android, multiplayer

I want to make quiz game that allow multiplayer in realtime. The player can play alone (offline) or with other (online), so can you tell me how should I storage my database? on local assert or database server? Thanks!

Comment: Kindly share with us what you have tried so far so that we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you support play alone when unconnected server, you use client database.
if you want show same quiz on multiplayer, server send quiz number every player.
when client receive quiz number, you can use quiz number for display quiz in client database.

Comment: No. your app have 1 database. On server, if player want connect another player make game room and connect between players. game is start, server send players one random number between quiz number.